# Insert text after specific word using batch

Tags: xml, text, batch-file, append

I have a series of XML files which I need to add a few lines of text to however the placement of the additional text is very important otherwise the XML file won't work anymore.

Luckily the new text needs to be inserted after the text `<Tools>` which only occurs once in each XML file.

How can I using Windows batch, find the text `<Tools>` and the insert the additional text directly after that? (for argument's sake lets say the text to be added is `<HELLO WORLD>`)

Kind regards

EDIT:

I just realized that I need to replace all instances of `<Tools>` with `<Tools> <HELLO WORLD>`

How can I do this?

EDIT 2:

the following is vbs which works well but not with quotation marks

Is there a way to replace text with the text contents of another file

```
    Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Text.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "CH1", "*901*")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Text.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do the quotations that cause problems come into play?

Is there a way to replace text with the text contents of another file? Do you mean replace just certain pieces with pieces from another file?

This below will find the string in the source file and output a new file with the insert.

```
:: Hide Command and Isolate Scope with Command Extensions
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:: See the following for help
rem echo /?
rem setlocal /?
rem for /?
rem type /?
rem find /?
rem del /?


:: Setup
set "xIn=Test.xml"
set "xOut=Output.xml"
set "xTerm=<Tools>"
set "xInsert=^<HELLO WORLD^>"


:: Validate
if not defined xIn goto End
if not defined xOut goto End


:: Place on Seperate Line Method
if defined xOut if exist "%xOut%" del /f /q "%xOut%" > nul
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`type %xIn%`) do (
    echo.%%a >> %xOut%
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%x in (`echo."%%a" ^| find "%xTerm%"`) do (
        echo.%xInsert% >> %xOut%
    )
)


:: Setup
set "xOut=Output2.xml"


:: Validate
if not defined xOut goto End


:: Place on the Same Line Method
if defined xOut if exist "%xOut%" del /f /q "%xOut%" > nul
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`type %xIn%`) do (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%x in (`echo."%%a" ^| find /v "%xTerm%"`) do (
        echo.%%a >> %xOut%
    )
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%x in (`echo."%%a" ^| find "%xTerm%"`) do (
        echo.%%a %xInsert% >> %xOut%
    )
)

:End
endlocal
```

**EDIT:** Here is a modified version of the above script that will replace a line containing the search term with the contents of a file.  It should handle quotations fine.  See the call command in the script to see how to use it.

```
:: Hide Command
@echo off

set "xResult="
call :ReplaceWith xResult "Source.xml" "<Tools>" "Input.xml" "Output.xml"
echo.%xResult%

goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:ReplaceWith <xReturn> <Source File> <Search Term> <Input File> <Output File>
:: Replace a line in the source file containing the search term with the entire
:: contents of the input file and save the changes to the output file.
:::: Note: Only supports single line search terms.
:: Returns the number of lines replaced.  -1 for error.

:: Hide Commands, Isolate Scope, and Set Abilities
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:: Setup
set "xResult=-1"
set "xSource=%~2"
set "xTerm=%~3"
set "xInput=%~4"
set "xOut=%~5"

:: Validate
if not defined xSource goto EndReplaceWith
if not exist "%xSource%" goto EndReplaceWith
if not defined xTerm goto EndReplaceWith
if not defined xInput goto EndReplaceWith
if not exist "%xInput%" goto EndReplaceWith
set "xResult=0"

:: Search
type nul > %xOut%
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`type "%xSource%"`) do (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%x in (`echo."%%a" ^| find /v "%xTerm%"`) do (
        echo.%%a>> %xOut%
    )
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%x in (`echo."%%a" ^| find "%xTerm%"`) do (
        type "%xInput%" >> %xOut%
        echo.>> %xOut%
        set /a "xResult+=1"
    )
)
:EndReplaceWith
endlocal & if not "%~1"=="" set "%~1=%xResult%"
goto :eof
:: by David Ruhmann


:End
endlocal
```

Comment: the quotation marks are found throughout such as <Tools Revision="18.2.1" option="0">.

Comment: I was also more thinking to replace the text <Tools> with the total contents of another text file...

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be safer to use or construct an XSLT and apply that to keep the XML valid? If you are willing to explore this option, I would recommend using e.g. a command line xslt processor like [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) (free community edition) to use in your batch files.
Many IDE/code editors, e.g. Visual Studio/Notepad++/Emacs/Eclipse/…, also have ways to apply and even debug XSLT (sometimes integrated, sometimes using plugins or add-ons), which may be handy while composing the transform.